# Adding a function with parameter to a variable

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function that receives an argument:

```
function test(arg)
{
    alert(this.id);
    alert(arg);    
}
```

I want to attach this function to a variable:

```
variable.addEventListener('mouseup',function (ime_igraca) {

                    test(ime_igraca);
                });
```

And I want this in function test to refer to the variable on which mouseup happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's just impossible: You can't attach an eventlistener to a variable because a variable that not supports events !

You have more informations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (MDN documentation ;) )

But, why you want to add an `addEventListener` to your `variable` ? What is your problem ? And where does the variable `ime_igraca` come from ?

### Edit

Maybe you just want to send existing variable to a listener like that :

#### JS

```js
let myElement = document.getElementById('myElementId');
let ime_igraca = "Foo";

myElement.addEventListener('mouseup',function () {
  test(ime_igraca);
});

function test(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<button id="myElementId">My Button</button>
```

Comment: My variable is an element from the page and the variable ime_igraca comes from the argument of a function.

Comment: Okay for the variable if it's an element ;) . 
But, I don't understand your problem with the `ime_igraca` Oh, wait, I edit my post for the problem I think you have ;)